# update query return true but not updating data in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have check all the parameters and they are having the correct data in them but my query is not updating data in table.

Here is the code :

```
public function updateRooms($capacity,$rent,$h_id,$t_rooms){
    $conn=DB::connect();

    for($i=1; $i<=$t_rooms; $i++){
        $room_no=$i;
        $sql= "UPDATE room SET ro_capacity='{$capacity[$i]}', ro_rent='{$rent[$i]}', ro_room_no='$room_no' WHERE h_id=".$h_id;

        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            echo "New record created successfully.". $last_id;
        }else{
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Just for caution, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: rows are matching $h_id contains the value 18 and in database there is also the same value

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in getting insert id from UPDATE query. It won't get you anything useful.

Besides, you should be using prepared statements.

```
public function updateRooms($capacity,$rent,$h_id,$t_rooms){
    $conn=DB::connect();

    $sql= "UPDATE room SET ro_capacity=?, ro_rent=?, ro_room_no=? WHERE h_id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("iiii",$ro_capacity,$ro_rent,$i,$h_id)
    for($i=1; $i<=$t_rooms; $i++){
        $ro_capacity = $capacity[$i];
        $ro_rent = $rent[$i];
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "The record updated successfully";
    }
}
```

As you can see, mysqli is almost unusable with prepared statements. This is why you have to use PDO:

```
    $sql= "UPDATE room SET ro_capacity=?, ro_rent=?, ro_room_no=? WHERE h_id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    for($i=1; $i<=$t_rooms; $i++){
        $stmt->execute([$capacity[$i],$rent[$i],$i,$h_id]);
        echo "The record updated successfully";
    }
}
```